# python operator overloading implement: __ge__ using __gt__ and __eq__

Tags: python, overloading, operator-keyword

I am overloading the operator methods.
Is it ok to implement `__ge__` using `__gt__` and `__eq__` ?

Why is it good/bad practice ?

```
def __gt__(self, other):
  pass
def __eq__(self, other):
  pass
```

```
def __ge__(self, other):
  return (self > other) or (self == other)
```

Comment: That's basically what [`functools.total_ordering`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/functools.py#L81) does.

Comment: It's very rare that it's *not* ok to do it; it's almost always what you want `>=` to mean.

Comment: It's good practice because it's easier to guarantee that the comparators have consistent behavior if you can implement some in terms of the others.  This is often a benefit of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) in general; redundant versions of the same logic can drift apart and become inconsistent, centralized logic can't.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you are asking about the idea of composing `__ge__` from `__gt__` and `__eq__`, rather than the actual `>` syntax.

If it's good enough for the [standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/functools.py#L138)….

```
def _ge_from_gt(self, other):
    'Return a >= b.  Computed by @total_ordering from (a > b) or (a == b).'
    op_result = type(self).__gt__(self, other)
    if op_result is NotImplemented:
        return op_result
    return op_result or self == other
```

`type(self).__gt__` is used, I think, to avoid triggering the use of `other.__le__` in the non-implemented case.